# Is "es" with "an" not equal to "daran"?

Tags: compound, separable-verb

I was trying to translate the sentence **I am looking at it again** on Duolingo. I put **Ich sehe daran wieder**, but they wanted **Ich sehe es mir wieder an**. The reflexiveness is not throwing me off, but why can't I replace **es + an** with **daran**?

Comment: What made you believe you could? "daran" is an adverb. "es" is an object and "an" is part of the verb. There's no rule whatsoever saying that you can replace an object and a part of a verb with an adverb.

Comment: @Em1 It's not that easy.

Comment: @Grantwalzer... yes, it is.

Comment: @Emanuel For non-native speakers this is far from obvious. Such comments discourage people to ask perfectly reasonable questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your *an* is not the same *an* as in

> Ich glaube nicht an dieses Zeug.

Here, *an* is a preposition. In your case, *an* is part of the verb *ansehen*. *An* is indeed separable, but you cannot use it (together with a preposition) to form a pronominal adverb.

---

**Additional clues**

`daran glauben` is a verb(al syntagma) whereas `daransehen / daran sehen` is not (at least not in the sense of looking at something).

To be replacible, it would have to be `an + object` (preposition), not `object + an` (some other construction).

**Further use of "daran"**

Even though *es* can be an object, phrases like

> Er denkt nicht an es. (ouch)

are considered informal if not wrong. Here, `an es` has to be replaced with *daran*. On the other hand, if the object is not a thing, then daran cannot be used. So A saying

> Ich glaube nicht an Gott.

cannot lead to B saying

> A glaubt nicht daran.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you couldn't use da-words with separable prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Ich dachte daran. Dieses "daran" ist eigentlich "das+an", wobei sich dasan zu daran
entwickelt hat. Und dasan ist eigentlich rückwärts zu lesen also als "an das".
Man könnte auch sagen die Präposition wurde hintenangehängt, wie das in anderen Sprachen oft der Fall ist.

I'm looking at it again kann man nicht mit Ich sehe daran wieder übersetzen.
Das würde heißen: Ich sehe an das wieder. Und das ist kein normales  Deutsch.
Ich sehe/ schaue mir das wieder/ nochmal an wäre eine brauchbare Übersetzung.

Comment: Ich fürchte, mit dieser Erklärung kommt man nicht in allen korrekten Verwendungsfällen von *daran* aus. *Daran sieht man...* oder "Man erkennt daran,..." würden mit dieser einfachen Ersetzung auch falsch klingen.

Comment: Die Verbkonstruktion ist: sich etwas anschauen, also ich schaue es mir an. Hier liegt kein Fall vor, wo man daran verwenden müßte.

Comment: Ja, das ist mir klar. Ich habe deine Antwort (besonders den zweiten Teil) so verstanden, als könne man *daran* durch *and das* ersetzen und so herausfinden, ob die Verwendung von *daran* korrekt wäre. Das ist aber nicht der Fall, daher mein Einwand.

Comment: Ich habe darüber nachgedacht. Es ist zu unterscheiden, ob das Verb ein Akk-Objekt hat oder ein Prep-Objekt:etwas ansehen hat ein AkkObjekt, also: ich sehe es an. An etwas denken hat ein PrepObjekt, also: ich denke daran (nicht: an es).

Answer (score 0):

**Da-words** can only be build with prepositions. "An" is not a preposition here but an adverb that has become part of the verb.

One clue as to the role of "an" is its being in final position. The more important one though is the fact that it does not connect anything to the rest of the sentence. Used as a preposition it would always look like this:

> ... an + [es/etwas/den Tisch/...]